# Java check if rotated too much after calculating shortest distance between angles

Tags: java, rotation

I found a post on how to calculate which direction to go to rotate the shortest distance to the right angle. But now I want to check if it rotated too much.

Here's the code:

```
if (angle < angleTo)
            {
                if (Math.abs(angle - angleTo) < 180)
                {
                    angle += deltaSeconds * 200;
                    //I want to test here
                }
                else
                {
                    angle -= deltaSeconds * 200;
                    //here
                }
            }

            else if (angle > angleTo)
            {
                if (Math.abs(angle - angleTo) < 180)
                {
                    angle -= deltaSeconds * 200;
                    //here
                }
                else
                {
                    angle += deltaSeconds * 200;
                    //and here
                }
            }
```

Comment: is that from my answer? :D btw, cant you just check each time the pointing error between your angle and the desired one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking if you've rotated the angle too far, I'd rather calculate the distance on beforehand, and if the distance is shorter than `deltaSeconds * 200`, just rotate by the remaining distance instead (or simply set `angle = angleTo`).

Also, you may want to make sure `angle` stays within the boundary [0,360).

EDIT: The following code will give you the distance:

```
double distance = Math.abs(angle - angleTo);
if(distance > 180) {
    distance = 360 - distance;
}
//If you want, you could replace the if-statement with this line:
//distance = (distance > 180) ? 360 - distance : distance;
```

Comment: I tried searching for the correct distance calculation, but I only found one without the code checking the shortest distance. angle and angleTo are always within the boundary.

Comment: @user1990950 I updated my answer. And as long as you check that `angle` is still within the boundary after the change, everything should be ok.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I detect what direction it needs to go without using the other code too?

Comment: @user1990950 You could set `angle = angleTo` if the distance is less than `deltaSeconds * 200`, and put the rest of your code in an `else`-statement. (I.e. if the distance is not less than `deltaSeconds * 200`)